# Role wise editing and delete permissions on a node

Tags: views, users

I have a drupal7 site and I need to implement this functionality into the site. I have two user roles(private and public), if a user of public role creates a node then all the users of public role should be given the edit and delete permissions for that node but the users of the private role should only be able to view the node and vice-versa. I have two views for two different roles and I want the edit and delete link to appear in those views for the user having same role as the role possessed by the node author, Please tell me how to achieve this programmatically as I have been searching for a module that can perform this functionality and there is no such module.